# How do I convert this PHP regex to Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I tried converting this:

```
$regex = "/^[0-9]+[0-9\.]*(?<!\.)$/"
```

to all of these, but none are correct:

```
var regex = /^(?!\.$)[0-9]+[0-9\.]*/;
var regex = /^(?!.*\.$)[0-9]+[0-9\.]*/;
var regex = /^[0-9]+[0-9\.]*(?!\.$)/;
```

The PHP regex correctly rejects `1.1a` and `1.`, but the javascript regex's do not.

Comment: Are you trying to be clever with negative look-aheads?

Comment: possible. I'm trying to get a string that has only numbers and dots and cannot end in a dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PHP Regex may be better written as the following, which matches the same language, but is easier to read and doesn't need to use a negative look-behind:

```
$regex = "/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/"
```

It is also easy to translate it directly to a Javascript regex:

```
var regex = /^\d+(\.\d+)*$/;
```